# How to center an input tag in fieldset when using codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, css

I have created a signup page using Codeigniter and I want to center all of the elements in a fieldset.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<fieldset style="text-align:center">
<legend>Data</legend>

<?php
$this->load->helper('form');

echo form_open('login/create_user');
echo form_input('username', '', 'placeholder="Username"');
echo form_input('email', '', 'placeholder="Email"');
echo form_password('password', '', 'placeholder="Password"');
echo form_password('password1', '', 'placeholder="Confirm"');

echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');
echo validation_errors();
?>
</fieldset>
```

CSS code:

```
input[name=username], input[name=email], input[type=password]
{
display: block;
margin: 0 0 1em 0;
width: 200px;
border: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 1px;
-webkit-border-radius: 1px;
padding: 1em;
}

input[name=submit]
{
border: none;
margin-right: 1em;
padding: 6px;
font-size: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
background: #088A08;
color: white;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
}
```

Here is how this look like: [Page](http://tinypic.com/r/65sewx/8), and as you can see, only Submit button is centered, why is it so?

Comment: It's all about CSS not CodeIgniter framework. Better to post the HTML output instead of CI helper functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input[name=username], input[name=email], input[type=password]
{
display: block;
margin: 0 auto 1em; /* change here */
width: 200px;
border: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 1px;
-webkit-border-radius: 1px;
padding: 1em;
}
```

You can always center a display:block using a width and margin-right: auto, margin-left: auto;